# Silverlight. Cannot call javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, sharepoint-api

I use sharepoint client api to save item to list. Then i need to call javascript function to update my html. But i cannot! Page is refreshed instead of function call!

```
         clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(
                    (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        delegate()
                        {
                            StopLoading();
                            HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("UpdateHtmlDetails", id, title, description);
                        });
                    }, SaveRequestFailed);
```

id = int, title= string, description= string
Why page refreshed intead of call to javascript?

Function inside some methods.js
 and registered:

```
   <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="/_layouts/tv2/js/methods.js" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>
```

File is presented on page is 100%.

Comment: Have you verified (debugged) that your JavaScript function is not called?

Comment: not called. Because was exception in silverligh... Out of browser property was on. Кстати мог и по-русски ответить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem. enable out of browser was on!